# 差し入れをお届けしたいとのことで

Tags: meaning

> お館様に内密で**差し入れをお届けしたいとのことで**、私が鍵をお貸ししました

I don't understand this part. "To do X (without you knowing it), I lent them my key" is all I can understand. I'm not satisfied with the translations I found of 差し入れ and とのこと(で), it doesn't make sense when I try to put them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「差{さ}し入{い}れ」 means a present (often, if not always, of food/drinks) and any free online monolingual dictionary would have it as it is a very basic and everyday kind of word.

「～～とのこと」 means "I am/was told ~~~."

> "I lent (someone) the key because I was told s/he wanted to secretly deliver a present to the lord/master."

Comment: @l'électeurThank you. What about で after とのこと? Could it be a way to say "because"?

Comment: @Ushiromiya The で is the continuative form (or, the te-form) of the copula だ. It connects clauses like... "(clause) and (clause)" or "(clause) so (clause)".